# Run output on Different Tabs

Tags: pycharm

I use Pycharm 2016.1.2 to display the outputs of different *.py files (in same project) on different run tabs. I'm having trouble getting different files to show output on same Run Tab.

How can I get this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You have to press the "pin" button on the "Run Tool Window", it's on the same column as the "Rerun" button just above the "Close" button.

Like it says on the [PyCharm help](http://http:/https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-tool-window.html):

> Use to pin or unpin the tab. If a tab is pinned, the results for the next command are shown on a new tab.